# Postgres | V9.4 | Extract value from json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table that one of the columns is in type TEXT and holds a json object inside.
I what to reach a key inside that json and ask about it's value.
The column name is json_representation and the json looks like that:

```
{
    "additionalInfo": {
        "dbSources": [{
            "user": "Mike"
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to get the value of the "user" and ask if it is equal to "Mike".
I tried the following:

```
select
json_representation->'additionalInfo'->'dbSources'->>'user' as singleUser 
from users 
where singleUser = 'Mike';
```

I keep getting an error:
Query execution failed

**Reason:
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: text -> unknown
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 31**

please advice
Thanks

Comment: Fix the schema and use the right data type, `json` or `jsonb` instead of `text`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Additionally you need to address an array element: `->'additionalInfo'->'dbSources'->0->>'user'` And you cannot use the alias in the `WHERE` clause, repeat the expression.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you what to do: *you might need to add an explicit type cast*:

And as you can not reference a column alias in the WHERE clause, you need to wrap it into a derived table:

```
select *
from (
   select json_representation::json ->'additionalInfo'->'dbSources' -> 0  ->>'user' as single_user 
   from users 
) as t
where t.single_user = 'Mike';
```

`::` is Postgres' [cast operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS)

But the better solution would be to change the column's data type to `json` permanently. And once you upgrade to a supported version of Postgres, you should use `jsonb`.

Comment: Thank you this helped! I just begun my sql  journey so still not sharp on the syntax and error messages

Comment: on the other hand, I ran the query that you wrote and I received the same error but regarding the t.single_user so I tried to add ::text like that  t.single_user::text and the result was empty although there is 'Mike" in the table.

Comment: @TalLevi: as `dbSources` is an array, you need to add an additional step to specify which array element you want. See my edit